# How allow users to select the theme color?

Tags: theme-development

I am developing a WordPress theme. I have seen that many theme give option to users to select the theme color?

How do I do that? They are doing it via filter? Which method they use to give option to give users to select the theme color?

Comment: They're using the Customization API: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/

Answer (score 0):

For admins: I would register an option page in wp-admin and would render some kind of color selecting gadget, that when changed, changes the value of an input field, and then render that color in a template in a style block to change the main color.

For registered users, suppose you could do it with  a plugin like *Extra User Details*.

If you need to change it on the fly, you must use JS, and all the elements that need to change have to have some unique classes.